# Holder vs RecylerView.ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have `ListView` with `Adapter`, and also use holder. but later I read about `recyclerView.ViewHolder` and now confused, Is it different with the one I've been using right now?  I mean for the optimization purpose, I want to know if using holder only is not good enough without using `recyclerView`.

```
    public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {

    Context context;
    List<News> myList;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<News> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.myList = objects;
    }



    @Override
    public News getItem(int position) {
        if(myList != null)
            return myList.get(position);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder;

        if (convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_news, null);

              holder = new NewsAdapter.Holder();

            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            holder.datePosted = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewThumbnailpic);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{

             holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();

        }


        News news = getItem(position);

        holder.title.setText(news.getTitle());
        holder.datePosted.setText(news.getDatePost());

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(news.getImgUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.coin25)
                .error(R.drawable.hnbspic)
                .into(holder.imageView);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class Holder{

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title;
        TextView datePosted;


    }
}
```

Comment: `RecylerView.ViewHolder>ViewHolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use Recyclerview because it has been optimized for various scenarios and not just for View holder pattern like it give the option for determining how your item should be laid out or like what should be the animation or custom drawing in each item.You can read more [this](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-things-about-the-new-recyclerview-1795df6f94c9) medium post